# CCXT how to refresh prices automatically?

Tags: python, ccxt

when querying exchange APIs, to get the latest price do I simply keep calling my fetchPrice() method every minute or so? I can get the price once, but is the proper way to update using CCXT to simply keep on fetching?  The use case is for a simple market scanner

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Feel free to edit this same question anytime to [improve it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). That will help others understand the problem, test it themselves and provide an answer. Usually, a code snippet that reproduces the problem helps other users to test it themselves.

Answer (score 3):

It would have been nice to have some of your code to help you solve this question. Anyway you need to use `asyncio` event loops.

There are many tutorials online on how to use `asyncio` but I found [this one](https://tutorialedge.net/python/concurrency/asyncio-event-loops-tutorial/) particularly helpful when I started out.

Here is the code below to get the bid / ask every second on deribit exchange but you can reflace that with any exchange that is supported by ccxt and it will work the same way:

```
import asyncio
import ccxt

async def cctx_prices():
    deribit = ccxt.deribit()
    while True:
        ticker = deribit.fetch_ticker('BTC-PERPETUAL')
        print(ticker)
        
        bid = ticker['bid']
        ask = ticker['ask']
        print(f"{bid} / {ask}")
        
        # pause asyncio for 1 second
        await asyncio.sleep(1) 

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.ensure_future(cctx_prices())
loop.run_forever()
```